# Why Android Studio can't reference a library if included in build.gradle only?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, guava, android-gradle-plugin

In my app I'm using Guava library. I have referenced it in my `build.gradle` file only as follows:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:13.0.1'
 }
```

My app rebuilds and runs fine. However when I'm trying to add a new something from Guava library then the compiler complains that it can't find the class.

For example: when I write

```
import com.google.common.base.Preconditions
```

in my new file the compiler says `'cannot resolve symbol common'`.

But my old files are rebuilt fine. How so? Do I have to mess with `Project|Structure`? I specifically wanted to list any dependencies  -only- in `build.gradle`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that doing a "sync project with gradle files" helps.

In Android Studio, select :

Tools > Android > Sync project with gradle files

Comment: I've been fighting with this all morning, and couldn't figure out why this wasn't working. In Android Studio 0.3.6 this resolves the problem, and we can fully handle dependencies with gradle. Awesome, should be accepted as the answer.

Comment: Is there a comparison for intellij?

Comment: not working for me i am using android studio version 3.0

Comment: Ever figure this one out @pfrank? Stuck with IntelliJ right now with an external dependency that I've successfully added to the class path but I can't reference any of the code.

Comment: Sorry anon, if I did I don't recall