# Can't reference an android library if included in build.gradle only (in IntelliJ)?

Tags: android, maven, intellij-idea, gradle

Similar to this question, [Why Android Studio can't reference a library if included in build.gradle only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19131036/why-android-studio-cant-reference-a-library-if-included-in-build-gradle-only).

I add a library to IntelliJ's Gradle that doesn't exist in Maven.  It seems to accept the library (if I change it to nonsense, it complains).

BUT, I can't import for the project in IntelliJ (like the build system knows about it but IntelliJ doesn't).  In Android Studio, there was a sync gradle button but that button isn't there in IntelliJ.  What do I have to do to get the project to recognize the new reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open/close IntelliJ and clean build everything